# How to convert a Unicode code point `Int` to a `Character` in Swift

Tags: swift, unicode

Unicode code point `0001F680` (integer value `128640`) is the rocket ship emoji:

How can I take that integer and convert it into a `Character` in Swift?

E.g:

```swift
let rocket: Character = toCharacter(128640) // What method do I use here?
```

Comment: `let rocket = Character(UnicodeScalar(128640)!)` but you might want to avoid the force unwrap. `String` also has an initialiser that takes a `UnicodeScalar` parameter.

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question but if you are trying to decode an Hex/Unicode string to Character you can apply a string transform as follow: `"U+1F680".applyingTransform(.init("Hex/Unicode-Any"), reverse: false)` // `""`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert an `Int` to an emoji character via `UnicodeScalar` but this returns an optional.

The `toCharacter` function can be written

```
func toCharacter(_ integer: Int) -> Character? {
    guard let scalar = UnicodeScalar(integer) else { return nil }
    return Character(scalar)
}
```